# Finding the middle character in a word

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do you find the middle character(s) in a word in visual basic without using the if else statement? For example I type in the word STRENGTH into the textbox and when I click the button I should get EN in the textbox. If I put SOS into the textbox I should get O in the textbox.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Please try to be specific when asking questions, see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but see if this works for you. It is using the [`Mid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kyd8789%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method to pull the characters from the string and the [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method to set the start position and using [`Mod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the Length + 1 to add 1 to the Length of the returned result if the String.Length is even.

---

Modified example to add a function and to better go with OP's question.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox2.Text = middleOfString(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Function middleOfString(value As String) As String

        'Get start location of substring, if value.length is odd have we have to make sure the result of the division rounds up to the nearest integer
        Dim start As Integer = CInt(Math.Round(value.Length / 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))

        'Get length of substring 1 if value length is odd, 2 if value length is even
        Dim length As Integer = CInt((value.Length + 1) Mod 2) + 1

        Return Mid(value, start, length)

    End Function

End Class
```